# Combining base64 audio strings

Tags: react-native, audio

I am using react-native-live-audio-stream to capture microphone audio. It spits out base64 encoded audio chunks like so:

```
LiveAudioStream.on('data', data => {
  // base64-encoded audio data chunks
});
```

I am looking to combine these chunks to send off as a single base64 string that could be used as input to an speech-to-text service.

With the code above, I am doing the following:

```
let bufferedAudioData = [];
LiveAudioStream.on('data', data => {
    bufferedAudioData.push(data);
});
```

Then when appropriate, I am using the following code to combine the `bufferedAudioData` array by calling `combineBase64Audio(bufferedAudioData)`:

```
export function combineBase64Audio(base64Strings) {
    // decode the base64 strings to ArrayBuffers
    const buffers = base64Strings.map(base64ToArrayBuffer);
  
    // create a new ArrayBuffer to hold the combined audio
    const combinedBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(buffers.reduce((totalLength, buffer) => totalLength + buffer.byteLength, 0));
  
    // create a view for each ArrayBuffer and copy the audio data into the combined buffer
    let offset = 0;
    buffers.forEach((buffer) => {
      const view = new Uint8Array(combinedBuffer, offset, buffer.byteLength);
      view.set(new Uint8Array(buffer));
      offset += buffer.byteLength;
    });
  
    // encode the combined ArrayBuffer as a base64 string
    return arrayBufferToBase64(combinedBuffer);
}
  
function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    // decode the base64 string to a Uint8Array
    const binaryString = Buffer(base64, 'base64').toString()
    const binaryLength = binaryString.length;
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLength);
    for (let i = 0; i < binaryLength; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    // return the Uint8Array as an ArrayBuffer
    return bytes.buffer;
}

function arrayBufferToBase64(arrayBuffer) {
    // create a Uint8Array view of the ArrayBuffer
    const bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    // convert the Uint8Array to a binary string
    let binaryString = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        binaryString += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    return Buffer(binaryString).toString('base64');
}
```

What Ive been doing is sending the final base64 encoded string to an API to save to a file on disk so that I can listen to it. Unfortunately the audio file sounds like gibberish. I am importing the file into Audacity as raw data and updating the settings accordingly. Im setting the encoding to "Signed 16-bit PCM" (which I think is correct) but the rest of the settings should be correct.

What am I doing wrong here? Im guessing that the way Im combining the base64 strings is the issue, but maybe Im not verifying the output correctly?

**UPDATE:** I listened to an individual decoded chunk of audio from `LiveAudioStream.on('data'` and it sounds fine. The culprit is my combining code. Still not sure what is wrong with it.

Comment: Do the recordings sound okay individually?

Comment: @Abe Yes. Listening to one of the chunks (which is only just over 30ms), it sounds correct using the settings from above in Audacity.